# How to print "\t" in awk

Tags: awk

I need to read a file, ignore some lines and print the lines I want with their tab delimiters as strings i.e.
input line:-

`1      7579643 .       C       <DEL>   .       .       DP=417;DPADJ=1471;RO=417;AO=1054;AF=0.716519374575119;END=7579660;SVLEN=17;SVTYPE=DEL;SVCONF=HIGH       .       .`

output line:-

`1\t7579643\t.\tC\t<DEL>\t.\t.\tDP=417;DPADJ=1471;RO=417;AO=1054;AF=0.716519374575119;END=7579660;SVLEN=17;SVTYPE=DEL;SVCONF=HIGH\t.\t.`

Can this be achieved in awk?

At the moment I have this:-

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"}{gsub(/\t/, /\\t/); if ($1 !~/#/) print $1}' test.vcf`

But my output strings not showing the separators correctly:-

`1075796430.0C0<DEL>0.0.0DP=417;DPADJ=1471;RO=417;AO=1054;AF=0.716519374575119;END=7579660;SVLEN=17;SVTYPE=DEL;SVCONF=HIGH0.0.`

Happy to do it in plain bash or sed etc.

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/\t/, "\\t"); print }' <<< $'a\tb'` seems to work, it prints `a\tb`. Why are you using `/\\t/` instead of `"\\t"` as the string to substitue?

Comment: yeah not sure why I did that- it works as I wanted if I change to "\t" and "\\t"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have `FS="\n"` and I don't understand it in this context and could therefore be off with this one but:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\\t"}{$1=$1;print}' file
```

Explained:

```
awk '
BEGIN {       
    FS="\t"    # tab separated
    OFS="\\t"  # \t string separated
}
{
    $1=$1      # rebuild the record
    print      # output
}' file
```

(Maybe changing that `FS="\n"` alone would fix your problem, didn't try that, too many tabs to fix.)

Comment: Thanks, more succinct than mine, added in the if statement, but works well otherwise. Thanks! awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\\t"}{$1=$1; if ($1 !~"#") print}' output.vcf

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do the test **before** your script spends the time recompiling the record? `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS="\\t"} $1!~/#/{$1=$1; print}' output.vcf`. You seem confused about the difference between regexp delimiters and string delimiters. See the awk man page for info on what they are and when to use them.